# Strange error in logs caused by a line in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

Last night we decreased the MySQL fulltext config to 3 characters with the line `ft_min_word_len=3` in my.cnf.

Ever since, we've had intermittent errors in the mysql log of `/usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './database/table.MYI'; try to repair it`. As a result, certain records have not been able to be updated, we are yet to track down a common denominator between these records. Interestingly, PHP does not return an error and things the query executed just fine.

As soon as we comment out the `ft_min_word_length` line and restart the server it works again. Any idea what is going on and how I can get the FT to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange. Assuming you have backups, have you tried

```
REPAIR TABLE database.table;
```

Comment: This appeared to have fixed the problem! I guess it rebuilt the fulltext index.

Comment: The problem has come back again over the weekend :/